# Как открыть порт на роутере МГТС

Tags: порты

Мне для проекта на python нужно открыть порт на своём роутере, чтобы компьютер мог работать как сервер. Я умею это делать, в прошлом году это работало, но в этот раз ничего не помогает. Брандмауэр у меня выключен, роутер Sercomm RV6699. Я в настройках заходил раньше в NAT, прописывал диапазон и всё, но МГТС, видимо, нашаманили что-то, чтобы впаять платный статический IP. Может ещё что-то нужно? Никто не сталкивался?
Спасибо.

Comment: *открыть порт на своём роутере, чтобы компьютер мог работать как сервер* Так у тебя реальный IP или серый на WAN роутера?

Comment: @Akina, как выяснилось, серый, но, честно говоря, первый раз про такой бред слышу (что публичный IP может отличаться от WAN. Спасибо за ответ, я уже понял, что единственный вариант - купить их паршивую услугу.

Answer (score 1):

Следует отметить, что на ONT-роутерах или другом абонентском оборудовании МГТС блокирует только некоторые порты, причем на доступ извне (для доступа из LAN абонента к внешним ресурсам открыты все порты по всем протоколам).

На сайте провайдера приводится список заблокированных портов:

tcp – 21, 23, 25, 69, 80, 135-139, 161, 254, 255, 445, 7547, 8080, 9090, 58000;
udp – 69, 135-139, 161. ,
Реально открытие портов МГТС роутеров может потребоваться в случаях:

развертывания на оборудовании пользователя серверов, в том числе, игровых, WEB, ftp, прокси и пр.;
использования торрент-клиентов (для раздачи), софта файлообменной сети emule и аналогичных приложений;
эксплуатации или тестировании программ, использующих механизм сокетов для обмена с другими хостами в сети, в том числе, внешней;
необходимости удаленного доступа к компьютерам пользователя (например, при использовании удаленного рабочего стола или удаленного помощника, Windows, удаленного рабочего стола Chrome, программ AeroAdmin, AnyDesk, Radmin, TeamViewer и аналогичных).
реже, при использовании роутеров МГТС в качестве мостов для другого оборудования клиента.
Для большинства перечисленных случаев подходит универсальный алгоритм действий пользователя при открытии портов.
Как открыть порты на роутере МГТС
Если абонент столкнулся с необходимостью открыть порт МГТС на GPON роутере, он может попытаться сделать это самостоятельно.

Ответ на вопрос, как открыть порты на роутере МГТС GPON, зависит от используемой модели маршрутизатора. В общем случае открытие портов для приложений осуществляется в разделе настроек NAT роутера.

ONT SERCOMM RV6699
Для открытия портов необходимо:

Войти в меню роутера используя ВЕБ-интерфейс (по IP-адресу устройства) или непосредственное подключение маршрутизатора к компьютеру по USB.
Авторизоваться с использованием пары логин/пароль (предоставляется МГТС при поставке настроенного оборудования).
Перейти в пункт NAT в меню настроек (левом меню интерфейса).
Для программ, использующих технологию UPnP выбрать соответствующий пункт в подменю NAT,
Убедиться, что включены UPnP IGD, режим «Настраиваемый» и NAT Traversal.
Показать таблицу маршрутов NAT Traversal.
В таблицу внести изменения вручную, включив необходимые порты (диапазоны портов).
Для приложений, требующих ручного проброса портов выбрать в подменю NAT пункт Port Mapping.
Выбрать приложения, для которых производится настройка из списка или указать другое («Задать сервис пользователя»), выбрать адрес LAN для сервиса.
В таблице для каждого приложения включить проброс портов, задать описание и диапазон портов для входящих и исходящих соединений.
При необходимости сделать настройки в Port Triggering (для обхода файерволов), DMZ (работы в защищенной зоне), ALG (шлюзов приложений).
Сохранить настройки и перезагрузить роутер.
GPON ZTE F670
Открытие портов на ZTE F670 производится практически аналогично Для настройки в меню роутера следует выбрать пункт «System Management»-«Usеr configuration Mangement». Затем выбрать UPnP или Port Forwarding, выбрать приложения из списка или внести в него новые и прописать порты входящих и исходящих соединений. После сохранения настроек перезагрузить маршрутизатор.

Аналогичные действия следует проделать на других моделях оборудования (если они еще не заменены на описанные выше).

Что для этого потребуется
Возможна ситуация, когда на роутерах МГТС проброс портов не работает совсем или доступ для приложений остается открытым ограниченное время.

Основная причина – серый динамический IP, который получает оборудование в локальной сети пользователя. Порты остаются закрыты провайдером, а после изменения адреса настройки port mapping оказываются неактуальны.

Чтобы однозначно решить проблему абоненту потребуется «белый» IP-адрес, получить который можно заказав в МГТС статический IP.

Следует отметить, что в этом случае большинство проблем с портами решаются автоматически без дополнительной настройки маршрутизаторов.
Возможные проблемы и нюансы
При открытии портов на роутерах МГТС абонент может столкнуться с некоторыми проблемами. Самые распространенные из них:

После настройки порты не открываются. Проверить правильность выполненных действий можно, посетив после настройки сайт 2ip.ru и проконтролировав открытые порты для запущенных приложений. Если необходимые порты остались закрытыми следует проверить сделанные настройки или все же обратиться в провайдеру для покупки белого IP.
Не сохраняются настройки роутера. Некоторые модели «страдают такой болезнью», особенно при попытке прописать порты диапазоном. В этом случае вопрос может решить перепрошивка маршрутизатора (выполнять только опытным пользователям или обратиться в поддержку провайдера).
Главная проблема открытых портов – снижение безопасности в локальной сети абонента.
Бороться с ней он должен самостоятельно, используя для этой цели антивирусные программы, брандмауэры и файерволы и другой софт.

Comment: убрал спам-ссылку: приведённая в ответе информация взята явно не по этой ссылке.